# Identifying source table from UNION query, given that both tables having duplicate values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I stumble upon this question, [SQL - Identifying source table from UNION query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404890/sql-identifying-source-table-from-union-query), but how about when both tables have the same row data, and column? How are we able to identify which table it came from? Is there another option to do it other than `UNION/UNION ALL`?

Example:

This is Table_1

```
+--------+---------+------------------+-----------------+
| ID_No  | ID_Type |      Data        | Input_Timestamp |
+--------+---------+------------------+-----------------+
|  1101  |  1000   | LARGE MANGO X12  |    2019-12-21   | 
+--------+---------+------------------+-----------------+
|  1102  |  1000   | LARGE BANANA X12 |    2019-12-22   |
+--------+---------+------------------+-----------------+
|  1103  |  1000   | LARGE ORANGE X12 |    2019-12-23   |
+--------+---------+------------------+-----------------+
|  1104  |  1000   | LARGE GRAPES X12 |    2019-12-24   |
+--------+---------+------------------+-----------------+
```

This is Table_2

```
+--------+---------+------------------+-----------------+
| ID_No  | ID_Type |      Data        | Input_Timestamp |
+--------+---------+------------------+-----------------+
|  1101  |  1000   | LARGE MANGO X12  |    2019-12-21   | 
+--------+---------+------------------+-----------------+
|  1102  |  1000   | LARGE BANANA X12 |    2019-12-22   |
+--------+---------+------------------+-----------------+
|  1103  |  1000   | LARGE ORANGE X12 |    2019-12-23   |
+--------+---------+------------------+-----------------+
|  1105  |  1000   | LARGE GINGER X12 |    2019-12-25   |
+--------+---------+------------------+-----------------+
```

Doing `UNION` like this will not work because they will be duplicated.

```
SELECT 'from_table_1' as from_table, ID_No, ID_Type, Data, Input_Timestamp FROM Table_1
UNION 
SELECT 'from_table_2' as from_table, ID_No, ID_Type, Data, Input_Timestamp FROM Table_2
```

Is there a way for this to be plausible? Or is there any other way for this to work?

This will be my expected output.

```
+--------------+--------+---------+------------------+-----------------+
|  from_table  | ID_No  | ID_Type |      Data        | Input_Timestamp |
+--------------+--------+---------+------------------+-----------------+
| from_table_1 |  1101  |  1000   | LARGE MANGO X12  |    2019-12-21   | 
+--------------+--------+---------+------------------+-----------------+
| from_table_1 |  1102  |  1000   | LARGE BANANA X12 |    2019-12-22   |
+------------+----------+---------+------------------+-----------------+
| from_table_1 |  1103  |  1000   | LARGE ORANGE X12 |    2019-12-23   |
+--------------+--------+---------+----------------+-----------------+
| from_table_1 |  1104  |  1000   | LARGE GRAPES X12 |    2019-12-24   |
+--------------+--------+---------+------------------+-----------------+
| from_table_2 |  1105  |  1000   | LARGE GINGER X12 |    2019-12-25   |
+--------------+--------+---------+------------------+-----------------+
```

The only reason why I want this to work is for me to be able to distinguish where the data came from and be able to color-code it in the front-end, because Table_2 will be the final data, and Table_1 can still be edited if necessary.

> To summarize, Table_1 will be prioritized in displaying the data before Table_2 if there are duplicate values in Table_1 and Table_2.

Thank you.

Comment: Edit your question and show the results that you want.  I am unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Fixed it. Please check.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know what rows data comes from you can use `union all` and aggregation:

```
select ID_No, ID_Type, Data, Input_Timestamp, count(*) as num_tables
from ((select ID_No, ID_Type, Data, Input_Timestamp, 1 as which
       from table1
      ) union all
      (select ID_No, ID_Type, Data, Input_Timestamp, 2 as which
       from table2
      )
     ) t12
group by ID_No, ID_Type, Data, Input_Timestamp;
```

Then if you only want rows in one table you can add `having count(*) = 2` into the table.

Note:  This version assumes that there are no duplicates within each table.

EDIT:

If you want to *prioritize* the rows, you can specify that as:

```
select t1.*, 'table1' as which
from table1 t1
union all
select t2.*, 'table2'
from table2 t2
where not exists (select 1
                  from table1 t1
                  where t1.id_no = t2.id_no
                 );
```

This only grabs `id_no`s once between the two tables.  You can add additional comparisons on the other columns if you want exact duplicates.

Comment: I added details to the question, please check. ID_No's 1101-1103 is the same in Table_1 and Table_2.

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm missing here, i followed your query structure, but I am unable to achieve the desired result, only Table_1 data is showing on my end.